# How can I have one Solution with Two .Net Core projects and use both Startup.cs files to setup services?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm sure I'm probably designing this wrong but I've got a solution with two projects. One project is the data access and the other is the web app. Both are .Net Core 2.1. I'd like to have configuration settings and dependency injection for both but I'm realizing that may not be possible.

The code below is in my data access `Startup.cs` except it's obviously not the main startup project, also it's a class library so that changes things. It doesn't use the `Startup.cs` and that file is the only place I've seen with .Net Core to setup configuration and services for dependency injection. Where else would I set this up?

So is it possible to set up DI with a class library? Am I creating the data access as the wrong project type? I'd like to use some other way instead of hard coding a connection string, like the appsettings.json or a key vault to get connection strings in the data access but I don't know any other way to set that up. The only way I can see is to hard code the string into the context class itself.

Any insight on what I'm doing wrong would be appreciated, thank you.

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(
        IConfiguration configuration, 
        IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        configuration = builder.Build();
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ISDeptContext>(options => 
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("PublicDatabase"));
        });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are doing something wrong :P "data access" should be a **class library**, not an application. Only **APPLICATIONS** (more specifically ASP.NET Core applications) have a startpoint. Class libraries don't, since you don't run them on their own. There is no need to add anything special to your class library to have it work with DI, except that you should use interfaces as constructor dependencies rather than concrete classes. Remember, the DI is configured at the **composition root*, this is the **earliest** point in your application where you can configure it. here Startup.cs

Comment: Figured. I have a context class but I have a repository and repository interface. I guess the main thing I'm trying to figure out is how I can setup the context with the connection string without hard coding it.

Comment: You must include the DbContext  in main project.

Comment: The repository interface and implementation is in the class library. Will the main project pass its DI context to that repository? Or should I be leaving the interface in the data access and the implementing the repository in the main project?

Comment: I'm going to answer the question giving credit to you guys because you both basically answered it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Llazar and @Tseng above pretty much answered the issue. It cannot be done. What I was trying to do was not something normal. I didn't realize but the `context` class can be included in the main project and that will get passed around in the main project DI. I can setup the connection string in the main project `Startup.cs` and get it from `appsettings.json` or user secrets or key vaults.